# Can I limit how many levels the .include adds with LINQ and Entity Framework 5?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Given the following:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

If I turn lazy loading off and issue the following:

```
        var departments = _DepartmentRepository.GetAll()
            .Include(c => c.courses);
```

Then I get the answers with a Department object inside of them.

Is there a way I can just include the courses and not get back the Department object. For example can I just include one level (courses).

Comment: did you figure out the best way to achieve this? I am struggling with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are just including one level. The department object inside the course is there because EF has done some relationship fixup so that you can navigate to the department from the course.

If you don't want departments then just get the courses directly. That is `context.Courses.ToList();` or via a courses repo if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

When fetching entities EF will automatically populate navigation properties where it is already tracking the target object.  This means if you do say:

```
// Load the department with a PK of 1
_DepartmentRepository.Find(1);
```

and then, using the same context, for example:

```
// Load a course with PK of 17
_CourseRepository.Find(17);
```

If this courses department id is 1, then EF will have automatically populated it's Department navigation property even though you didn't specify the include.  You could stop this behavior by not making the Department navigation property virtual.